# JavaScript: Google map scrolling

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scripting

Does anyone have any idea how to make a google map scroll to the right continuously?

I know most people try to get this to stop but i want to create a function in javascript that makes it scroll.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var step = 1 /*px*/;
var timespan = 100 /*ms*/;
setInterval(function(){map.panBy(step, 0);},timespan);
```

here's a working demo http://radarvicieux.com/permis-a-points?scroll

Comment: doesn't work. i created a function that initializes the map and i know there is a way to do it with panBy but i dont know how

Answer (score 0):

Send a "button down" event via JavaScript, but never send the "button released" event.

Comment: i used on mouse move. so when i have the cursor on the map it moves. the thing is that i am changing the position of the map the Latlng everytime it detects the mouse over the map. and it's not really efficient because it's not a continuous movement but frames.